# Finding cheapest values from a user input for a product

Tags: matlab

recently I was given a word problem where I had to write a program that takes a user input of the number of a product and the finds the cheapest way the user can buy the amount of that product. Values are as follows: product 1 is a 24 pack that sells for $109, product 2 is a 12 pack that sells for $55, product 3 is a 4 pack that sells for $19, and product 4 is a 1 pack that sells for $5. The program should tell the user the cheapest way to buy the product.

Comment: Naturally, I only need an explanation. I have tried representing the products as an array and then assigning the price to the values but where I get completely stuck is thinking of what to use to get the cheapest values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if it is an explanation you need.

1. you want to first work out your average price per unit, this means doing $109/24, $55/12 and $19/4. This should give you different values for each individual unit.
2. Next Assume you want to buy x Units, you need to take x and find the package with lowest cost, see if x is greater than that values. So for example, if x is 21, then the 24pack would not be an option. EDIT here, your question do not specify, but if x is 23 and 24 pack happens to be cheaper than any other combination, would you be allowed to purchase the 24 pack? If so, for stage 4, you want to always consider going for the bigger package to see if it is cheaper, you need to add an extra decision there.
3. If x is greater than the cheapest package, you want to do x mod package size. Where the mod stands for modulo divide.
4. If x is not greater than the cheapest package, you want to take the next cheapest package size and see if x is greater than it.

You continue to loop back and forth step 3 and 4, until there are no smaller options (unless you also happen to sell them individually, in which case, you would use it).

and finally you add up all your packages * package price

=========================================================

Method 2, you can consider a combination problem, your goal is to combine any number of 24,12,4 packs and combine them to form your desired unit x. Then work out which one is cheapest. What is interesting is that if you allow buying more then you need (given that it is cheaper), you need to add a set of combinations to those generated and compare their prices. For example if x is 35, you want to run possible combinations for 48 (24*2), 36 (3*12) as well as 35.

Comment: So say I wanted to buy 143 units, I would mod 143 and 12 since it is the. Lowest price per unit? This would return 11 and for two other values like 4 and 1 would return 0